Search within array of custom objects within dictionary
I have a dictionary where key is of type string and value is an array of custom objects. I am working on search UI, where when user searches on something, app should check for search term within one of the properties of that custom object. However, I am getting some error.
import SwiftUI

struct Book: Hashable {
    var bookName: String
    var authorName: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let bookData: [String: [Book]] = ["Fictional": [Book.init(bookName: "titleA", authorName: "AuthorA"), Book.init(bookName: "titleB", authorName: "AuthorB")],
                                      "Non-Fictional":  [Book.init(bookName: "titleCA", authorName: "AuthorC")]]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World")
        }
        .onAppear {
            let matchingResults = bookData.filter({ $0.value.filter({ $0.bookName.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains("A") }) })
            
            // Expecting below output since book names have 'A' in it.
            // ["Fictional": [Book.init(bookName: "titleA", authorName: "AuthorA")], "Non-Fictional":  [Book.init(bookName: "titleCA", authorName: "AuthorC")]]
        }
    }
}

In the above example, if I search for 'A' or 'a', the output should be
["Fictional": [Book.init(bookName: "titleA", authorName: "AuthorA")], "Non-Fictional":  [Book.init(bookName: "titleCA", authorName: "AuthorC")]] since "titleA" and "titleCA" contains A.
But instead I am seeing following error "Cannot convert value of type '[Employee]' to closure result type 'Bool'" on line where I am filtering the data i.e. "searchResults = groupedEmployees.filter({ $0.value.filter({ $0.fullName.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchTerm) }) })"
How do I search within array of custom objects in a dictionary?
